# Display animal GPS movements using gganimate

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I want to display GPS locations of an animal's movement within the study site. I got to display the GPS locations (.csv file) using gganimate:

```
p <- ggplot(data1, aes(x = Long, y = Lat)) + 
  geom_point(aes(colour=Number), show.legend=FALSE)
p   
plot(p)

anim <- p + 
  transition_states(Number,
                    transition_length = 2,
                    state_length = 1)
```

but I haven't been able to set the raster of the study site (.tif file) as background. Any idea?

Also. The `transition_states` function only runs 100 frames, I want to run 663 frames (all the GPS locations) and it seems like using (nframes=663, fps=24) does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same challenge. To set the study background, I first used the `ggmap()` function to set a terrain map as the plot background. This method won't work for uploaded your own image, but used satellite imagery from Google. You should be able to do this with you code using:

```
library(ggmap)
bbox <- make_bbox(lon = data1$Long, lat = data1$Lat, f = .1)
terrain <- get_map(location = bbox, maptype = "satellite")
p <- ggmap(terrain) +
     geom_point(data = data1, aes(x = Long, y = Lat, colour = Number), show.legend = FALSE)
anim <- p + transition_states(Number, transition_length = 2, state_length = 1)
```

`make_bbox()`generates the boundary for your study site, given the input from `data1`